# foreach on $_POST input array returns duplicate fields

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a large table that generates the input fields dynamically based on information in a database. Upon submit, the form data is sent via ajax to another php file. I need to retrieve the ids of domains that are in particular input fields to run other queries. If I echo back the ids that are retrieved from the query, and the ids are, for example, "2" and "3", it returns "2", "2". When the page refresh occurs, the input fields become duplicates of each other.

These are all fake values, so it's safe to show what I'm working with. The SOA fields are static, but every subsequent field is dynamically created.

[image: table]

Without even changing input values, I click update, refresh the page, and this happens:

[image: duplicates!]

On the Network tab (XHR Response), this is the data that is sent back before the page refresh/duplication happens.

```
"10""@""10""localhost""Success"
```

Everything but "Success" will be gone later. I'm just echoing them back for debugging. As you can see, the queries show duplicate domains, when they should actually be "10" and "11".

I will start with the table page to show how the fields are dynamically generated. I'll only show one block for the sake of brevity (there are 5 blocks of this).

```
<?php
$a_count = $db->count("SELECT * FROM records WHERE domain_id=? AND type=?", [$domain_id, $type['A']]);
if ($a_count > 0) : ?>
<!-- ALL OF THE LABELS ABOVE THE INPUTS -->
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-2 " style="font-weight:bold;">
             Host
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2" style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:30px;">
             IP
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2" style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:30px;">
             TTL
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2" style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:30px;">
            Timestamp
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2" style="height:20px;width:210px;"></div>
         <div class="col-sm-2" style="font-weight:bold;width:100px;margin-left:160px;">
            Delete
         </div>
     </div>
     <!-- GET THE RECORDS TO DISPLAY IN ONE ROW OF INPUTS -->
     <?php
     foreach ($records = $db->getRows("SELECT * FROM records WHERE domain_id=? AND type=?", [$domain_id, $type['A']]) as $record) {
         $rid_a = $record['id']; ?>

         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="A_host[]"
                                       value="<?php echo escape($record['name']); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-left:30px;">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="A_ip[]"
                                       value="<?php echo escape($record['content']); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-left:30px;">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="A_ttl[]"
                                       value="<?php echo escape($record['ttl']); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-left:30px;">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="A_timestamp[]"
                                       value="<?php echo escape($record['change_date']); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2" style="height:20px;width:100px;"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-left:80px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" style="margin-top:15px;margin-left:195px;" name="A_delete_checkbox" value="<?php echo escape($rid_a);?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php }
       else:?>
       <!-- OTHERWISE, SHOW THERE ARE NO RECORDS -->
           <div class="row">
                NO A RECORDS AVAILABLE
           </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the portion of my jQuery that submits the form:

```
$('#edit_zone_form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var isEmpty = false;
        $(':input:not(:button):not(:checkbox)').each(function () { //First, check if any inputs are empty. If empty, show dialog.
            if ($(this).val() === "") {
                var error_text = $('#dialog p').text("All fields are required");
                $('#dialog').html(error_text);
                $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Error').dialog('open');
                isEmpty = true;
                console.log("Submitted form. isEmpty = " + isEmpty);
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(!isEmpty) {
            console.log("Passed if(!isEmpty) " + isEmpty);
            var error_text = $('#dialog_confirm p').text("Please confirm your update\nbefore proceeding."); //Confirm they want to do that
            error_text.html(error_text.html().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
            $('#dialog_confirm').dialog('open');
        }
        $('#confirm_button').click(function () { //Confirm button becomes a 'submit' button for ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: 'domain-edit-check.php?id=' + <?php echo json_encode($domain_id);?>, //domain_id used in destination file
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('#edit_zone_form').serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response === "Success") {
                        var success_text = $('#dialog p').text("Domain Successfully Updated.");
                        $('#dialog').html(success_text);
                        $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Success').dialog('open');
                        $('#dialog').on('dialogclose', function() {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                location.replace('domain-edit2.php?init=1&edit_domain=' + <?php echo json_encode($edit_domain);?>);
                            }, 500)
                        });
                    }
                   //THE REST OF THE CONDITIONS (error, etc)
            });
        });
    });
```

And finally, the php that does the processing (note - $db->getRow is a custom function and has worked throughout the application until this):

```
//domain-edit-check.php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $CLIENT_IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $DATE_TIME = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $domain_id = $_GET['id']; //domain_id passed from ajax url string

    //There are no duplicates of these. They are static inputs
    $SOA_content_field = array($_POST['SOA_NS'], $_POST['SOA_Contact'], $_POST['SOA_Serial'], $_POST['SOA_Refresh'], $_POST['SOA_Retry'], $_POST['SOA_Expire']);
    $SOA_content_param = implode(" ", $SOA_content_field);
    $SOA_update = $db->updateRow("UPDATE records SET content=?, ttl=?, change_date=? WHERE domain_id=? AND type=?", [$SOA_content_param, $fields['SOA_TTL'], $DATE_TIME, $domain_id, 'SOA']))

    //After the top inputs, check all of the dynamic inputs with the update_ok function.
    //Send back results based on the outcome.
    if (update_ok($domain_id) === true) {
        echo json_encode("Success");
        $db->disconnect();

    } else {
        echo json_encode("Failure");
        $db->disconnect();
    }
}

function update_ok($domain_id)
{
    $passed = false;
    $db = new DB();

    //The different types of records for queries
    $types = array(
        'A' => 'A',
        'NS' => 'NS',
        'MX' => 'MX',
        'CNAME' => 'CNAME',
        'TXT' => 'TXT'
    );
    //CHECK ALL OF THE DYNAMIC INPUTS FROM THE FORM
    //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM BEGINS
    foreach ($_POST['A_host'] as $key => $value) {

        //GET THE ID FOR ALL OF THE INPUTS AND MAKE UPDATES BASED ON THAT UNIQUE ID

        if($result = $db->getRow("SELECT id FROM records WHERE domain_id=? AND type=?", [$domain_id, $types['A']])) {
            $id = $result['id'];
            //echo json_encode($id);
            //echo json_encode($value);
            if ($update = $db->updateRow("UPDATE records SET name=? WHERE id=?", [$value, $A_host_result['id']])) {
            $passed = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //DO THE SAME FOR THE REST OF THE INPUTS (Minimum of 15 more. Some have 2-5 of each)
    foreach ($_POST['A_ip'] as $key => $value) {

    }
    foreach(etc etc as $etc => $etc) {
        //etc etc etc...
    }
```

Why is my id being duplicated if I'm looping over the $_POST array? If the id did not duplicate, my problem would be solved. I have tried this function on as a standalone chunk of code on a test page and it returns the information properly. Something is wonky with my foreach($_POST), I just don't know what.

Comment: Have you looked at the data in the table using PHPAdmin or similar?

Comment: Why isn't the ip address part of the update clause?

Comment: @SloanThrasher because I haven't cleaned it up yet. I'm trying to get past this obstacle. I'm doing each input group separately for now. I will eventually group them together.

Comment: And I'm working with a headless server. Can't view phpmyadmin. But I'm running tail on the mysql.log and the SELECT statements are duplicating the ids. If I group them together, then all of the fields will duplicate, causing more work for me to manually run queries to revert the error in terminal.

Comment: What's `$A_host_result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using record id in your inputs.

In HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="A_host[<?php echo $rid_a?>]" 
       value="<?php echo escape($record['name']); ?>">
```

In PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['A_host'] as $id => $value) {
    if ($update = $db->updateRow("UPDATE records SET name=? WHERE id=?", [$value, $id])) {
        $passed = true;
    }
}
```

And so on for the rest of inputs.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know placing the code within the array brackets was a thing. My MySQL log is showing the correct ids, and my inputs update correctly now, but for some reason my ajax is echoing back duplicate ids again. Despite that bug, it's working and I will accept.  Thank you. Do you know why my Response in the dev console would still be showing duplicate ids?